# ¿Cómo redirigir el crawler de Disqus?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, mod-rewrite

Disqus, al parecer, no encuentra los metadatos en mi aplicación web y como no los encuentra cuando alguien comenta un artículo escoge texto al azar de la página. Utilizo [esta directiva](https://github.com/michaelbromley/angularUtils/tree/master/src/directives/disqus) de AngularJS. sí sirve de algo redirijo los crawlers de las redes sociales hacia una página estática con php y Apache, Alguien sabe si Disqus tiene un crawler como Facebook, twitter o google, igual que estos:`RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} (facebookexternalhit|Twitterbot|Pinterest|Google.*snippet)`

**Controlador:**

```
app.controller('dirDisqusCtrl', ['$scope', function($scope){
    $scope.disqusConfig = {
      disqus_shortname: 'appname',
      disqus_identifier: window.location.href,
      disqus_url: window.location.href
    };
}]);
```

**HTML:**

```
<article ng-controller="dirDisqusCtrl">

  <dir-disqus config="disqusConfig"></dir-disqus>

</article>
```

**.htaccess:**

RewriteEngine On

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} (facebookexternalhit|Twitterbot|Pinterest|Disqus|Google.*snippet)
RewriteRule ^news/([-._a-z0-9]+)$ http://miweb.com/php/crawler.php?id=$1 [NC,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !index
RewriteRule (.*) index.html [L]
```

Answer (score 0):

Efectivamente, como lo has mencionado tu mismo en la pregunta, el crawler de disqus se identifica a sí mismo con el user-agent: **"Disqus/1.0"**

Por tanto, puedes añadir una regla de redirección para este, o añadirlo a una regla existente, según te convenga.

Comment: ¿Puedo implementarlo sólo como **"Disqus"** o es necesario el **"/1.0"**? Lo digo por si hay una versión nueva no tener que cambiar el "/1.0"

Comment: Si, recomendaría solamente disqus, justamente para que no haya problema con el cambio de versión.

Comment: Por alguna razón no me funciona, he agregado a mi pregunta mi **.htaccess** a ver si puedes ver que sucede. No se porque no se marca correctamente el código en mi pregunta.